# MS Access update query not updating errors out

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in Access that I started as a Select Query.  I am getting the correct results and am trying to update a specific field in a table with the results.  How do I do that?  This is an elapsed time from when someone took possession of a room in a house to current date. The calculated field works but for some reason whenever I try to change it from select to update it errors out.

```
Field = Days: DateDiff("d",[entrydate],Now())
Update to=[Rates].[TotalDays]
```

> Error=DateDiff("d",[entrydate],Now()) is not a valid name. Make sure
>   it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that the
>   name is not too long.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the entire SQL statement. Sounds like you're assigning the wrong way round

Comment: Why even save this calculated value? It can be calculated when needed.

Comment: @Erik So I used the Query builder to build it and not SQL, So not sure what I can provide

Comment: So I have two fields EntryDate and ExitDate, but I need the calculation to show in TotalDays the elapsed time between the wo unless the ExitDate is Null and then use Now() as the total number of days is then run against their daily rate to come up with a rolling balance.  Just a contextual note, this is for Tenant/Clients in Addiction Recovery Sober Living home that require some state reporting.